# Query repeating event in a given time range

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a set of events (Time in `MM/DD`) that can be repeated by different users:

```
EventId   Event     Time                   User
1         Start     06/01/2012 10:05AM      1
1         End       06/05/2012 10:45AM      1
2         Start     07/07/2012 09:55AM      2
2         End       09/07/2012 11:05AM      2
3         Start     09/01/2012 11:05AM      2
3         End       09/03/2012 11:05AM      2
```

I want to get, using SQL, those events a user has done in a specified time range, for instance:
Given `06/06/2012` and `09/02/2012` I am expecting tho get:

```
EventId   Event     Time                   User
2         Start     07/07/2012 09:55AM      2
2         End       09/07/2012 11:05AM      2
3         Start     09/01/2012 11:05AM      1
```

Any idea on how to deal with this?

Comment: What is the type of the `Time` column?  Are you really using the MySQL database engine?

Comment: its Timestamp. I am using Snowflake, syntax is similar to SQL

Comment: Is your timestamp data shown as MM/DD or DD/MM?

Comment: Time is in MM/DD

Comment: I'm lost.  How is user 1 associated with event 3 in the result set?  Why is `09/07/2012 11:05` in the result. set but not `09/03/2012 11:05`?

Answer (score 0):

A basic range query should work here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Time >= '2012-06-06'::date AND Time < '2012-09-03'::date;
```

This assumes you want records falling on June 6, 2012 to September 2 of the same year.